# Editing in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

you know how you are able to Edit a record on a GridView by clicking Edit button. I have programmed my code in such a way that when clicks Edit button on GridView, a new window pops up with all the details of the record given in respective fields.

I also have search-feature in my program. That when a user clicks search button after entering some referenced information in the given fields on search page, the desired record or records (if more than 1) show up at the bottom of the search page in a GridView list. Ofcourse with Edit button option in case user wants to Edit the search-record.

could you please help me in guiding how to edit a searched record in a gridview because when when I click Edit to change searched-record,my program opens the first record from the list of all records in the database table (and doesn't open the record that I clicked on to EDIT) in a new window.

My code for edit row record is:

```
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        //BindGridView();
        lblSet.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(vRecord);

        btnInsert.Visible = false;
        //this.lblMedium.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text;


        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIMS;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                String sql = "select [DocumentsID],[Ref],[Subject],[Src],[Dst],[Medium],[Date_Printed],[Date_Received],[Document_Type],[Action_Required],[Due_Date],[Actual_Date],[Content],[Tag],[Issue_No],[Attachment],[Notes],[Assigned_To],[Reply_Ref],[Priority],[Status],[Response] from dbo.Documents where [DocumentsId]=N'" + GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text + "'";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                con.Open();

                //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);
                //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adp.Fill(ds);

                }

                this.txtRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                this.txtSubject.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
                this.ddlSource.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
                this.ddlDestination.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
                this.ddlMedium.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                this.txtDatePrinted.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
                this.txtDateReceived.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
                this.ddlDocumentType.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();
                this.cbxAction.Checked = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][9].Equals(cbxAction.Checked);
                this.txtDueDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString();
                this.txtActualDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][11].ToString();
                this.txtContent.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();
                this.txtTag.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][13].ToString();
                this.txtIssue.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][14].ToString();
                this.txtAttachment.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][15].ToString();
                this.txtNotes.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][16].ToString();
                this.ddlAssignedTo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][17].ToString();
                this.txtReplyRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][18].ToString();
                this.ddlPriority.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][19].ToString();
                this.ddlStatus.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][20].ToString();
                this.ddlResponse.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][21].ToString();


                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
```

Code for Search Function is:

```
   protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       String sql = "select * from PIMS.dbo.Documents";
       bool flag = false;
       if (!txtRef0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Ref =N'" + txtRef0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Ref =N'" + txtRef0.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!ddlDst.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Dst =N'" + ddlDst.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Dst =N'" + ddlDst.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!ddlSrc.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Src =N'" + ddlSrc.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Src =N'" + ddlSrc.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!txtSubject0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Subject =N'" + txtSubject0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Subject =N'" + txtSubject0.Text + "'";
           }
       }
       if (!ddlMedium0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Medium =N'" + ddlMedium0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Medium =N'" + ddlMedium0.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!ddlDocumentType0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Document_Type =N'" + ddlDocumentType0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Document_Type =N'" + ddlDocumentType0.Text + "'";
           }
       }
       if (!txtContent0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Content  LIKE N'%" + txtContent0.Text + "%'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Content  LIKE N'%" + txtContent0.Text + "%'";
           }
       }
       if (!txtTag0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Tag  = N'" + txtTag0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Tag  =N'%" + txtTag0.Text + "'";
           }
       }
       if (!txtIssue0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Issue_No= N'" + txtIssue0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Issue_No  LIKE N'%" + txtIssue0.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!txtNotes0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Notes LIKE N'%" + txtNotes0.Text + "%'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Notes  LIKE N'%" + txtNotes0.Text + "%'";
           }
       }

       if (!ddlAssignedTo0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Assigned_To = N'" + ddlAssignedTo0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Assigned_To  = N'" + ddlAssignedTo0.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!ddlPriority0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Priority = N'" + ddlPriority0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Priority  = N'" + ddlPriority0.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!ddlStatus0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Status = N'" + ddlStatus0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Status  = N'" + ddlStatus0.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!ddlResponse0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Response = N'" + ddlResponse0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Response = N'" + ddlResponse0.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!txtReplyRef0.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Reply_Ref = N'" + txtReplyRef0.Text + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Reply_Ref = N'" + txtReplyRef0.Text + "'";
           }
       }

       if (!txtDatePrintedF.Text.Equals("") && !txtDatePrintedT.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Date_Printed >=N'" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDatePrintedF.Text, "G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Date_Printed <=N'" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDatePrintedT.Text, "G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
           }
       }
       if (!txtDateReceivedF.Text.Equals("") && !txtDateReceivedT.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Date_Received >=N'" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateReceivedF.Text, "G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Date_Received <=N'" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateReceivedT.Text, "G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
           }
       }
       if (!txtDueDateF.Text.Equals("") && !txtDueDateT.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Due_Date >=N'" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDatePrintedF.Text, "G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Due_Date <=N'" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDatePrintedT.Text, "G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
           }
       }
       if (!txtActualDateF.Text.Equals("") && !txtActualDateT.Text.Equals(""))
       {
           if (flag == false)
           {
               sql = sql + " where Actual_Date >=N'" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDatePrintedF.Text, "G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
               flag = true;

           }
           else
           {
               sql = sql + "  and Actual_Date <=N'" + DateTime.ParseExact(txtDatePrintedT.Text, "G", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
           }
       }

       txtSQL.Text = sql;

       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIMS;Integrated Security=True"))
       {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = sql+";";
                //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                //dataset object to get all select statement results
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                //sql dataadoptor to fill dataset
                using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    //here all select statements are fill in dataset object
                    adp.Fill(ds);

                } this.GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // first select statement result
                this.GridView1.DataBind();


            }

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            txtSQL.Visible = false;
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(vGrid);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not retrieving your selected row, but you are retrieving the first row present in your `datagridview`. Your code:

```
this.txtRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString(); //you are referring to DataSet
                                                       //first row, which will always be same
```

You just need to change one thing:

Set a variable:

```
int SelectedRowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex; //it will return int value of selected row
```

Then replace `0` index of `Rows` in your code with `SelectedRowIndex` and `ds.Tables[0]` with `GridView1`:

```
this.txtRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString(); //your code
this.txtRef.Text = GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString();  //corrected one
//do this for your all 21 cells by changing cell indexes
```

Now it will select the row from your `gridview` not from the `DataSet`.

Note:

I have changed my entire answer because you didn't mentioned before that you are using **Web Controls**, not **Windows Form Controls**.

**Additional:**

This is how to check any condition:

```
if(SelectedRowIndex >= 0)
{
    GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: Dear Shaharyar, 

You have certainly understood my problem. Thats exactly what my program is doing (selecting the first row present in my datagrid). 

Now when I try to Set the variable as advised by you: 

int SelectedRowIndex = ds.Tables[0].SelectedRows[0];

Program is underlining "SelectedRows" in ds.Table[0].SelectedRows[0] in red in the code and is throwing following syntax error: 

Error 1 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRows' and no extension method 'SelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found

Comment: Did you change `0` with variable `SelectedRowIndex` ?

Comment: yes. my code is: 
int SelectedRowIndex = ds.Tables[0].SelectedRows[0];                    
                    this.txtRef.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[SelectedRowIndex][1].ToString();
                    this.txtSubject.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[SelectedRowIndex][2].ToString();

Comment: and for all the remaining rows .. same

Comment: then remove `Tables[0]` and use only `int SelectedRowIndex = ds.SelectedRows[0];`

Comment: Basically what error message means is .. when we try to add "SelectedRows[]" method to ds.Table[], Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 is telling that no such method exists. That is why when I add a dot (.) after ds.Tables[0] and intelisense list shows .. there is no such method as "SelectedRows" in it. We have to tackle this problem using other ways .. I think.

Comment: What is the `ds`? Is this a `DataSet` or `DataGridView` or something else?

Comment: It is DataSet bro. 

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

Comment: @RehanMehdi i've changed my entire answer. Check it again

Comment: Dear Shaharyar, I am very thankful to you for devoting time to my problem. I followed ur steps in my code i.e.,
int SelectedRowIndex = ds.Tables[0].SelectedRows[0];                  
                    this.txtRef.Text = GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

Now compiler is showing a red line underneath SelectedRows in:
int SelectedRowIndex = ds.Tables[0].SelectedRows[0]
and also underneath Value in:
GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

Comment: @RehanMehdi that was my mistake, i am correcting it again, check it. but what error in `GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();` ?

Comment: for the line: 
GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
code is throwing following error: 
Error 2 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: directives that I am currently using are: 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Globalization;

Comment: @RehanMehdi: It may be time to add some of this code into your post editing it as things progress. It's generally not suggested to continue in chatty back and forth in comments, but more important is the fact that you're using it to post code changes that aren't even in code blocks which is very difficult to read. Consider providing an **Update:** section that reflects what you've learned so far.

Comment: New changes in my code are: 
                    int SelectedRowIndex = GridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;                  
                    this.txtRef.Text = GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

Still showing a syntax error on SelectedRows and Value

Comment: @C.Lang Which Html tag do we use here in comment-field to enter our code. ?

Comment: " \` " at the beginning and another " \` " at the end. But still, the amount you're doing is borderline excessive to put it nicely. Things like => I tried `this.that.someOtherThing`, but it didn't work is good. You'll learn as go.

Comment: Ok C.Lang. will follow that

Comment: @RehanMehdi Now what error? and be professional, explain error not tell that something is underline.

Comment: @Shaharyar I changed my code how u instructed.Still have problem with `SelectedRows` method in `int SelectedRowIndex = GridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index` and `Value` property in `this.txtRef.Text = GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();`.

 Any clues?

Comment: I asked that what the error are there. keep your mouse cursor on the error place, and a popup will appear with error description. Tell me that description. Other wise every thing is fine in the code, there would be any other problem.

Comment: @Shaharyar: Editor underlines both `SelectedRows` and `Value` in red ... showing using them here is a syntax error.

Comment: for `SelectedRows` Error is: 
Error 1 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRows' and no extension method 'SelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: for `Value` Error is: Error 2 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @RehanMehdi again updated the answer, now read it carefully and implement it

Comment: @Shaharyar: Back from LunchBreak. Sorry to keep you waiting. Changes I made were: 
`int SelectedRowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;` and `this.txtRef.Text = GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString();`

Compiler is now throwing error on line:

`this.txtRef.Text = GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString();`

Error Description:
ArgumentOutofRangeException was unhandled by the user.
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @RehanMehdi this error would be coming at `runtime`. Because probably you haven't selected any row, place a check before `this.txtRef.Text = GridView1.Rows[SelectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString();` that `if(SelectedRowIndex >= 0)` and then put all cell data retrieving lines in that `if block`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'place a check' ?

Comment: @RehanMehdi `check` in programming is `checking` a statement using `if`

Comment: There is a control called checkbox. so when you check it .. its valued is checked. Dont know what other checking means.

Comment: @Shaharyar: Program is not executing If Blocked statements cause If Condition is never true. So program jumps to the rest of the code. Program is still outputting selection of 1st record from GridView1.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to simply say
gridview.editindex = e.neweditindex

or in other case if you using popup then i dont think its ideal way to fire row editing command, as you are not using its benefits

anyway

if it is possible to to pass a key to your query to fetch particular record
then you can find the data key values from your edit index row
and then pass this key with your query
it will return only that particular record,